# Moving a file into a newly created folder hangs on win8

Tags: windows-8

I have a simple bat file which does the following:

```
@echo off
mkdir folder1
mkdir folder2
echo.>file1
move file1 folder1\file1
```

When I run this on Windows 8 it will often hang the shell and explorer.

Interestingly, turning on/off the echo does seem to effect the chance of running into the bug (echo off hits the bug more often it seems) but I can get the bug either way.  Suggests a race condition of some kind.

Anyone have an idea why this hangs on Windows 8?  It doesn't on Windows 7.

I've also tried this using powershell.  It happens less often (had to do it about a hunderd times before I hit the problem) but still occurs.

Comment: eliminate gitbash from the mix. run the same batch file using purely windows commands and see if the same behavior occurs. if it does, then it's probably a windows problem. if it doesn't, then it's gitbash

Comment: I updated the script to use non-git-bash cmds just to be double sure.  The problem still occurs.

Comment: Are you running this script on a network share or SSD? I have interesting file flushing problems on my Win7 that cause similar issues, and I attribute it to my SSD. For example, Makefiles fail because of race conditions in the time stamps. I have to put in explicit delays and file flush commands (cygwin sync) to get things to work right. You might try putting a delay after the `echo`

Comment: This is actually on a VM but maybe its the same issue.  What exactly was the timestamp issue your referring to?  How did the timestamps cause problems?  I agree that what I'm seeing seems a lot like a race condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was a combo of antivirus and search indexer.  Both touch all the files in the FS as soon as they're created.  I also suspect that the test machine being a VM has something to do with it (it is likely a little underpowered).

tldr; turning off windows.search from services fixed things.